# Auto Log Off in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, visual-studio

In my database on my SQL Server I have a table with users. This table have a column named logged_on which is a bit, either true or false. When someone log on the column will be true, else false. If something ever happens when someone is using my wpf-application, like the power disappears and the application couldn't log out the user this column will be true and the user will not be able to login again, because the application will tell this user that he is already logged on. Is there something i could do to avoid this situation? On the server-side or in the application?

Any sugestions are appreciated :)

Comment: Do the clients run straight against the database or via some server layer? (yes, I see you're mentioning server-side, but not sure whether you mean SQL server or something else)

Comment: Why no just simple let the user silently log in again?

Comment: What is the goal of this? Are you trying to restrict the number of concurrent logon sessions, or the number of users logged in, or something else?

Comment: Use an actual membership provider.  Your current solution has to many problems to list.

Comment: Ramhound has good advice.  This problem has been solved before, many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to change the approach a little, perhaps tracking last interaction date/time (every time the WPF app calls SQL) and enforcing a session timeout limit instead.  You could use that DateTime to automatically log out anyone that hasn't interacted with the server in several minutes by checking it in addition to the *logged_on* bit field (always switching *logged_on* to false if the DateTime is too stale).

Is there an important reason you can't just throw away the old login in situations where the user logs in again without logging out first?

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll need a "LastActive" date-time stamp.  Then run a scheduled job that says "if you've been inactive for X minutes, change the state of the logged_on flag".

Are you trying to insure that only one login can be active at the same time?  Is that the end game?